# How to get a list of available metrics and dimensions for use with the Google analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

There are several metrics and dimensions - let it be a list.

For example:

> **Year** dimension and **New Session** measure.

How to get a list of available metrics and dimensions for this list via Google Analytics API java SDK V3 so that the error does not fall

> "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together"?

Answer (score 4):

## Dimensions and metrics list

> How to get a list of available metrics and dimensions for this list via Google Analytics API .

The first thing you need to understand is that the Google Analytics Core reporting API and the Google Analytics reporting APIs. Only return the data from within Google analytics. Neither has the power to return to you a list of dimensions and metrics.

To get a list of Dimensions and metrics that can be used in these APIs you should look at the [Meta data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) .  It returns a list of all the dimensions and metrics that can be used with the Google Analytics APIs to query Google analytics data.

## Example

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns

## Invalid dimension and metric reference.

> "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together"?

Message means that some metrics and dimensions just cant be queried together because there isnt the proper data relation between them. There is no api that will tell you which dimensions and metrics can be queried together.

You have two options:

1. You can use the [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) to check which dimensions and metrics can be used together they will be grayed out if they cant be used together.
2. You can just make a request as you have and check for an error.

Comment: Would the -1 care to comment i would be happy to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Sulution: take json from here https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/ga_cubes.json - this is a list of cubes. For each cube it contains the set of dimensions and metrics that it consists of.

The algorithm is as follows:
We run through the List (for example **Year** dimension and **New Session** measure), and look if at least one of these cubes has all the dimensions and metrics from the list, then such metrics and dimensions are compatible, otherwise not.

So it works in https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

However, it is worth considering that some metrics work together only when there is an additional dimension. For example: ga:14dayUsers, ga:newUsers works only with days dimension.

Comment: Hey. Do you remember how you found this cubes.json file? I am inspecting the page with Chrome Devtools, the code references this json file but it's nowhere to be seen